# bindable property for checkbox ischecked do not reflect when trigger used

Tags: wpf, checkbox, triggers

My bindable property `RevalSurfaceChecked` do not get updated when we set `IsChecked` property in trigger

```
<CheckBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Name="chkRevalSurface" Content="Export Reval Surface (if applicable)" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <CheckBox.IsEnabled>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource RevalSurfaceCheckboxEnableConverter}">
                    <Binding ElementName="ChkExportToCSV" Path="IsChecked"></Binding>
                    <Binding ElementName="chkExportToExcel" Path="IsChecked"></Binding>
                </MultiBinding>
            </CheckBox.IsEnabled>
            <CheckBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding RevalSurfaceChecked}" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </CheckBox.Style>
        </CheckBox>
```

The logic here is that if I check any of the two checkbox, then the `chkRevalSurface` should get enabled else stay disabled-written in converter. When `chkRevalSurface` is disabled it should be set unchecked (written in trigger) and `RevalSurfaceChecked` property should be set to `False`. if checked set it to `True` in viewmodel.

But`RevalSurfaceChecked`is not set to true or false.

Comment: Can you explain bit clear on what you are trying to achieve.  You have explained in your way of how it works and cannot be understood by anyone else.

Comment: when checkbox is enable, on check or uncheck - I can see the property "RevalSurfaceChecked" value changes in code.

Comment: But when It is checked, and on disable of checkbox it get unchecked but the value of RevalSurfaceChecked does not change to false

Comment: @AbhineetKumar can you give the property RevalSurfaceChecked or it's whole class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `<Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"></Setter>` clears the original binding, so your `CheckBox`'s `IsChecked` property just ends up being `False` without changing the underlying property.

You mentioned you have a viewmodel, I assume the `ChkExportToCSV` and `chkExportToExcel` `CheckBox`es are bound to a property in your viewmodel.

Lets assume this viewmodel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _revalSurfaceChecked;
    public bool RevalSurfaceChecked
    {
        get { return _revalSurfaceChecked; }
        set
        {
            _revalSurfaceChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool _isChkExportToCSVChecked;
    public bool IsChkExportToCSVChecked
    {
        get { return _isChkExportToCSVChecked; }
        set
        {
            _isChkExportToCSVChecked = value;
            RevalSurfaceChecked = RevalSurfaceChecked && (_isChkExportToCSVChecked || _ischkExportToExcelChecked);
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool _ischkExportToExcelChecked;
    public bool IschkExportToExcelChecked
    {
        get { return _ischkExportToExcelChecked; }
        set
        {
            _ischkExportToExcelChecked = value;
            RevalSurfaceChecked = RevalSurfaceChecked && (_isChkExportToCSVChecked || _ischkExportToExcelChecked);
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

And this XAML:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="ChkExportToCSV" Content="ChkExportToCSV" IsChecked="{Binding IsChkExportToCSVChecked}"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />

<CheckBox x:Name="chkExportToExcel" Content="chkExportToExcel" IsChecked="{Binding IschkExportToExcelChecked}"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />

<CheckBox x:Name="chkRevalSurface" Content="Export Reval Surface (if applicable)" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
          IsChecked="{Binding RevalSurfaceChecked}">
    <CheckBox.IsEnabled>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource AnyTrueConverter}">
            <Binding ElementName="ChkExportToCSV" Path="IsChecked"></Binding>
            <Binding ElementName="chkExportToExcel" Path="IsChecked"></Binding>
        </MultiBinding>
    </CheckBox.IsEnabled>
</CheckBox>
```

I'm binding the `ChkExportToCSV`'s `IsChecked` property to the `IsChkExportToCSVChecked` property in the viewmodel and the `chkExportToExcel`'s `IsChecked` to the `IschkExportToExcelChecked` property.

I removed the `Style` from `chkRevalSurface` and for the `IsEnabled` I use a converter that gives back `true` if any of the inputs are `true`. I assume your `RevalSurfaceCheckboxEnableConverter` does the same, but I'll include it here:

```
public class AnyTrueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values != null && values.OfType<bool>().Any(b => b);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The trick is in the setter of `IsChkExportToCSVChecked` and `IschkExportToExcelChecked`:

```
RevalSurfaceChecked = RevalSurfaceChecked && (_isChkExportToCSVChecked || _ischkExportToExcelChecked);
```

We moved the logic from the `DataTrigger` to here. This should solve your problem. I tested and it works for me.

Comment: This approach has already worked to me, the difference is that this trick I used in converter. Actually I was expecting some style in XAML only. I thought that binding Mode can help on this. but it seems that even it dint helped you to resolve so you tried this trick in c#. Thanks anyways.